# Action on Unpermitted Parameters on production environment

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html

Why `action_on_unpermitted_parameters` defaults to `false` on production environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three options:

- `false` - do nothing, filter unpermitted
- `:log`  - write a message on
  the logger
- `:raise` - raise an exception.

So, it would be pretty bad idea to set default value to `:raise` - it would lead to crashes.
So, we have to choose between `false` and `:log` - lets look at [implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/130370b1c872e9c7645e1c3cc26365d9dc4d90b1/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb) (starting at line 240) - log will be written with `debug` level, so it would not be visible in production with default logging level. There is just no point to store unpermitted params in production log in most cases.

Comment: Would it not be the best idea to catch `ActionController::UnpermittedParameters exception` on production and response with 400?

Comment: As default behavior - totally not ok. Imagine 3d party API to add extra parameter to POST query for some callbacks we are listening to in new release without any breaking changes - Rails app would just answer 400 to all requests. Personally, I would not like it in my app. Since they gave us `:raise` option, error handling can be done if needed.